# are async lambda functions on aws called in sequence?

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, parallel-processing, aws-lambda, cloud

It says that laws lambda is designed to run many instances of your function in parallel.

But underneath each lambda function there is a maximum age of event property that we set for asynchronous calls.

If you click on the information popup next to maximum age of event it tells you that we need a maximum age of event because incoming events are placed into a queue before being sent to the function. So does that mean there is only one asynchronous environment running all the incoming requests in sequence? Why can't asynchronous functions also be ran in parallel? Why do they need to be queued?

Comment: "They say this is because incoming events are placed into a queue before being sent to the function." - who's they and incoming events from where? Lambda functions can be triggered from 15 different services - the behavior could be different in some cases

Comment: They is aws lambda when you click the little information popup next to "asynchronous invocation maximum age of event"

Answer (score 0):

The batching depends on the service calling it, but lambda will definitely spin up parallel instances when being called asynchronously. How many depends on a number of things, like the batch size, the setting you reference above, transaction volume, and sharding. The last one is pretty key. When you work with something like Kinesis it will limit the calls to the number of shards. SQS FIFO queues have a similar limitation. Calls from SNS, on the other hand, may fan out to a large number of parallel invocations, because there is no guarantee of order.